# React Nodes and JSX Elements as const in Parent Component?

Tags: reactjs, web, jsx

If we have a lot of JSX code in our component, is it okay to assign some of it to a const, or should we always create new components and reuse them? I will post here some trivial examples.

Example 1, with const and inner JSX Element:

```
export const ParentComponent = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    const ChildNode = (
      <div>Hello World</div>
    );

    return (
     <div>
        {ChildNode}
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Count me</button>
     </div>
    );
};
```

Example 2, separate component:

```
const ChildComponent = () => <div>Hello World</div>;

export const ParentComponent = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    return (
     <div>
        <ChildComponent />
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Count me</button>
     </div>
    );
};
```

I know that declaring a child component inside a parent component is not good and we are messing with React rendering, but this also applies to simple JSX Element?

Answer (score 1):

> but this also applies to simple JSX Element?

No.

In code review we'd probably say don't make the variable name PascalCase:

```
    const childNode = (
      <div>Hello World</div>
    );
```

I know this is example is contrived, but

1. if the child node is so small, you should just declare it directly in the return:

```
    return (
     <div>
        <div>Hello World</div>
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Count me</button>
     </div>
    );
```

2. If the child node is big, you should create a new component and pass props

```
const renderSomething = () => /* some long block of jsx */

return (
  <div>
   {renderSomething()}
   ...some other jsx
 </div>
)
```

Is an anti-pattern - because those `renderXXX` functions tend to grow and get unwieldly and hard to follow over time

Comment: Yeah, my question referred to when the "childNode" is bigger and has props. 
I usually use a new Component for such cases (it will also help to test by doing it this way), but I was just wondering if it is also more performant/efficient.

Comment: @ComanVladut aim for clarity over performance until performance becomes a problem.

Comment: I used to use `renderXXX` style functions a lot. I now share the same opinion that they're really not a good idea. I also doubt it would have any performance benefits since the function is being redefined each render

Comment: @AdamJenkins Totally agree, but both options have pretty much the same clarity. In one I am using a variable as a JSX Element, in other is a new component for the JSX.

I've never said I was using renderXXX.My question was about the new component vs JSX as a variable (if in this case, is still an anti-pattern)

Comment: @BrianThompson I am not asking about rendeXXX - I know it is an anti-pattern and should be avoided. 

My question was if this anti-pattern applies also when declaring JSX as a variable (as I said in the post description)

Comment: How would it be different? They're more the same than not. Neither are used as components, one can use parameters the other can't. The function call won't observably affect performance. To me they're the same question